# Getting no search results with Solr edismax query parser

Tags: solr, edismax

I have **Solr version 5.2.1** up and running and I am trying to set specific boost parameters to my search fields. As soon as I specify the *edismax* defType and a *qf* parameter, I do not get any search results.

Here my examples:

**without boost**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=test&fl=title,description,score&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax


{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "fl":"title,description,score",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"test",
      "wt":"json",
      "defType":"edismax"}},
  "response":{"numFound":11,"start":0,"maxScore":0.4290576,"docs":[
      {
    "title":"Link-Test",
    "score":0.4290576},
      {
    "title":"Auth-Test",
    "score":0.4290576},
      {
    "title":"test",
    "description":"Description for the search result page",
    "score":0.3754254},
      {
    "title":"Footer Test",
    "score":0.3217932},
      {
    "title":"Slider-Test",
    "score":0.268161},
      {
    "title":"Credit card TEST",
    "description":"This is the description of the credit card page test",
    "score":0.1608966},
      {
    "title":"Service",
    "score":0.15169477},
      {
    "title":"Linklist",
    "score":0.13273293},
      {
    "title":"My target page",
    "score":0.13273293},
      {
    "title":"Some download page",
    "score":0.094809234}]
  }}
```

**with edismax boost**

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?q=test&fl=title,description,score&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&qf=title^20+description


{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":2,
    "params":{
      "fl":"title,description,score",
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"test",
      "qf":"title^20 description",
      "wt":"json",
      "defType":"edismax"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Do I have to activate ExtendedDisMax query parser somehow?
Here's my [solrconfig.xml](http://pastebin.com/ptmGnEvS)

Comment: Are title and description the only 2 fields you have? Also are they indexed?

Comment: no, there are additional attributes as well. title and description are both indexed. I do get some data, when I use a copy of titel -> attr_title and description -> attr_description

Comment: Post the field definitions from schema.xml